# sending print string command to remote machine

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, remote-desktop

I'd like to print some string to all open terminals processes that are running in remote machine. currently I'm using ssh to connect the remote machine, and than I echo my string into `wall` command :

```
local> ssh me@1.2.3.4
(prompt to provide credentials)
remote> echo "123" | wall
```

is there a way to do it all in one command that will run without user interactions ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to setup SSH key based authentication so that you do not need to enter a password.

1. On the client machine, run the following to copy your current user's publickey to the server's `authorized_hosts` file:

   ```bash
   ssh-copy-id me@1.2.3.4
   <enter password>
   ```
2. Make sure that you do not need to enter a password now:

   ```bash
   ssh me@1.2.3.4 true
   ```
3. Then simply append the command to the SSH command as following:

   ```bash
   ssh me@1.2.3.4 'echo asdf | wall'
   ```

You probably need to use the `-tt` flag with SSH, to ensure that you run the command in a TTY.

Note the single quotes `'`, they ensure that the pipe `|` does not get parsed by your local shell.

Comment: As an alternative to the single-quoted pipe approach, _if_ you have working passwordless login, you could instead use something like `echo asdf | ssh me@192.0.2.1 wall`. The difference is that in this form, the `echo` runs on the local system. Either way works in most cases, but running the command producing the message locally may allow for better error handling in some cases.